# jquery if element contains text, add class to parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a class to a parent div if one of the children elements contains the word "Sponsored."

```
<div id="post-item">   
  <span class="tags">
      <a href="#">Blogs</a>            
  </span>         
</div>

<div id="post-item">   
  <span class="tags">
      <a href="#">Sponsored by Lorem Ipsum</a>            
  </span>       
</div>
```

I am currently trying to use parent().addClass but it's not working for some reason. You can see an example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VrPdF/

```
if (jQuery('a:contains("Sponsored")').length) {
    jQuery(this).parent('#post-item').addClass('sponz');

}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated - thanks !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**IDs must be unique**, so use class to identify parent. You can use **.closest()** to identify parent with class `post-item`.

***HTML***

```
<div class="post-item">   
  <span class="tags">
      <a href="#">Blogs</a>  
    <h3>Lorem</h3>          
  </span>         
</div>

<div class="post-item">   
  <span class="tags">
      <a href="#">Sponsored by Lorem Ipsum</a>            
  </span>       
    <h3>Lorem</h3>
</div>
```

***JavaScript***

```
jQuery('a:contains("Sponsored")').closest('.post-item').addClass('sponz');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/VrPdF/5/)

---

[`:has()` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)  can also be used

> Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

```
jQuery('.post-item:has(a:contains("Sponsored"))').addClass('sponz');
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Comment: Thanks !! This is a great fix.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to check the length, it either returns an element or it doesn't, and you'll have to use `closest()`, as `#post-item` is not the immediate parent element.

I used classes as you can not use duplicate ID's

```
$('a:contains("Sponsored")').closest('.post-item').addClass('sponz');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VrPdF/2/)

Comment: Thanks !! This is exactly the reason it wouldn't work and a great fix.

Answer (score 1):

Following should be your javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('a:contains("Sponsored")').closest('#post-item').addClass('sponz');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krishanudey/VrPdF/6/)